# Browsers automatically evaluate hex or hsl colors to rgb when setting via element.style.background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, colors

I am not sure if I am missing something obvious but can somebody explain this to me? The following snippet is from what I did on Chrome DevTools Console. Same is the result for Firefox.

```
> let container = document.createElement("div")
> undefined
> container.style.background = "#bbb"
> "#bbb"
> container
> <div style=​"background:​ rgb(187, 187, 187)​;​">​</div>​
> container.style.background = "hsl(120, 50%, 50%)"
> "hsl(120, 50%, 50%)"
> container
> <div style=​"background:​ rgb(63, 191, 63)​;​">​</div>​
```

Here's the image for better readability.

Is this the standard behaviour? If so, how do I get to put the real HEX or HSL value in inline style?

[image]

Comment: Because that is what browsers do. Why do you need it in hex?

Comment: so that I can later query it back in the same form I set it. With the existing behaviour, I have to either convert it back or maintain a separate data attribute

Comment: Or use a css class and not worry about it. Than if you need to see if it has XYZ color, you would know to look for XYZ class instead.

Comment: I can't do that in my case because all the elements are generated from a data set which is just an array of colors in different formats. Strings. I would be okay with browsers behaving that way but I would like to know why they do it or a pointer to a spec that says it's what browsers should do.

Comment: I do not think there is a spec, some browser do hex, some rgb, some rgba. There are plenty of questions/answers on stackoverflow on how to read the color as hex.

Comment: The workaround I have is a `data-` attribute because I do not want to perform a computation for color conversion. :(

Comment: seems like a decent solution.

Comment: As a (late) side note: there is no "real hex" in the same way that there is no "real hex" for plain numbers in a browser. For example, `1e3`, `1000`, `0x3e8`, `01750`, and `0b1111101000` are just different ways for _you_, the programmer, to specify _the same number_. Internally it's a 64 bit 2's complement IEEE floating point bit pattern, JS does not track "what you wrote". The same goes for colors: `red`, `#F00`, `#FF0000`, `hsl(0,100,50)`, `rgb(255,0,0)` are all different ways to specify _the same color_, which is stored as a 32 bit value in which the bytes are R, G, B, and A, in that order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color):

> If the value is translucent, the computed value will be the `rgba()` corresponding one. If it isn't, it will be the `rgb()` corresponding one.

Meaning that no matter what is your input, the computed value **always** results in either `rgb` or `rgba`.

So, answering your question: **yes**, it is standard behaviour and **no**, you can't use hex or hsl as it will be computed back to rgba.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for pointing that out. I should have looked at spec for computed value. The funny thing is that I don't see the same happening for named colors like `green`, `white` etc.

Comment: I see this line everywhere by now, but I cannot seem to find it in the actual W3C spec. When I just google the line, it pops up on any color-related article on MDN, but I can't seem to find it in the actual spec (not even in their linked specs or the computed value spec)... Can you give me a direction on that?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is... **to use "outerHTML"** !
It's the only place from where we can extract the genuine color format.

```
function realBkgColor(elem){
    let outer = elem.outerHTML.replace(/\s/g,'');
    let tag = outer.split('<'+elem.tagName).pop().split('>')[0];
    let style = tag.split('style="').pop().split('"')[0];
    let color = style.split('background-color:').pop().split(';')[0];
    return color;
}
div = document.querySelector('div');
div.innerHTML = realBkgColor(div);
```

**returns "#ffff00"** and not "rgb(255, 255, 0)"

```
<div style="background-color: #ffff00"></div>
<!--
<div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0)"></div>
<div style="background-color: hsl(60, 100%, 50%)"></div>
<div style="background-color: yellow"></div>
-->
```

Try it with these...