# React inline-style turns green color HSL into white RGB

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How do I use a hsl color range in react for inline styles?
I'm passing the below as a property to `style`

`{backgroundColor: "hsl(100, 80%, 100%)", color: "black"}`

but instead I just get an rgb like this when I inspect the element:

`style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: black;"`

the code snippet is like:

```js
const colorPill = (sim) => {
    const sat = Math.round(sim.use * 100) // map
    const pillStyle = {
        backgroundColor: `hsl(100, ${sat}%, 100%)`,
        color: 'black'
    }
    console.log('pillStyle', pillStyle)
    return (<span className='pill' style={pillStyle}>use [{sat}]</span>)
}
```

btw I'm trying to do something like a heatmap where an item will get redder based on a percentage value passed in. perhaps there's an easier way to do this... but without bringing in lots of packages...

references:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Comment: This conversion seems to be default browser behavior but your code should still work fine.

Comment: no i think the JSX is outputting the rgb value instead of hsl

Comment: Answer can be found right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39211005

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browsers automatically evaluate hex or hsl colors to rgb when setting via element.style.background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208559/browsers-automatically-evaluate-hex-or-hsl-colors-to-rgb-when-setting-via-elemen)

Answer (score 2):

It's becoming white because the luminosity is set to 100%. For a 'pure' color, set the last number to 50%

```js
{backgroundColor: "hsl(100, 80%, 50%)", color: "black"}
```

I was stuck on the same thing for far longer than I should have been. I am leaving this awnser since none of the comments really helped me realize what i was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
<div 
style={{ 
  backgroundColor: `hsla(
                     ${hue}, 
                     ${saturation (*100 if btw 0 and 1)}% , 
                     ${light (*100 if btw 0 and 1)}%, 
                     ${alpha})` 
}}
...
</div>
```

you can use hsla values in inline style as show above