# JavaScript: Can't change the selected game mode

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a game where a color is given and then the player has to choose which is the correct color. There are three game modes: rgb, hex, hsl. I have given three buttons on the top to change the current game mode.
[image: Image representation]

After changing the game mode, the question asked must be changed to the same color code of the selected game mode. However, even though the changing of the question works fine, the colors in the options are changed in the same way as from the color code selected. Since I have defaulted the `selectedGameMode` to `rgb` somehow, the game runner only works in rgb. And even after changing the game mode, the game runner still uses the rgb as the selected game mode.
When I click on a button the following gets executed:

```js
let selectedGameMode = "rgb";
document.querySelectorAll(".colorCodeBtn").forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (btn.classList.contains("selectedColorCode")) return;
    btn.parentElement
      .querySelector(".selectedColorCode")
      .classList.remove("selectedColorCode");
    btn.classList.add("selectedColorCode");
    selectedGameMode = btn.getAttribute("game-mode");
    gameRunner();
  });
});
```

1. Here `colorCodeBtn` is the class given to the button to change the game mode and there are three of these as shown in the image.
2. Here `selectedColorCode` is a class added to the selected button and is turned white.
3. Here `game-mode` is an attribute given to these buttons to know which button changes the game to which mode.
4. `gameRunner` is a function that handles everything happening in the game.

When I used `console.log()` to display the currently selected game mode, it was displaying it correctly which means that this works.

So, maybe there is a problem here:

```js
function randomColorGenerator() {
  let red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  let green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  let blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  if (selectedGameMode === "rgb") {
    return `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
  } else if (selectedGameMode === "hex") {
    let hexRed = red.toString(16);
    let hexGreen = green.toString(16);
    let hexBlue = blue.toString(16);
    return `#${hexRed + hexGreen + hexBlue}`;
  } else if (selectedGameMode === "hsl") {
    let h = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
    let s = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + "%";
    let l = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + "%";
    return `hsl( ${h}, ${s}, ${l})`;
  }
}
```

This is a function that can generate random colors for us. I have tested this function many times and it works correctly. So, are the if cases not getting fulfilled here? If not, why because the `selectedGameMode` is correct according to the log. Here the `selectedGameMode` remains rgb even after changing it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

## Here is the code that I have currently

```js
let selectedGameMode = "rgb";
gameRunner();
document.querySelectorAll(".colorCodeBtn").forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (btn.classList.contains("selectedColorCode")) return;
    btn.parentElement
      .querySelector(".selectedColorCode")
      .classList.remove("selectedColorCode");
    btn.classList.add("selectedColorCode");
    selectedGameMode = btn.getAttribute("game-mode");
    gameRunner();
  });
});

function randomColorGenerator() {
  let red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  let green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  let blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  if (selectedGameMode == "rgb") {
    return `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
  } else if (selectedGameMode == "hex") {
    let hexRed = red.toString(16);
    let hexGreen = green.toString(16);
    let hexBlue = blue.toString(16);
    return `#${hexRed + hexGreen + hexBlue}`;
  } else if (selectedGameMode == "hsl") {
    let h = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
    let s = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + "%";
    let l = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + "%";
    return `hsl( ${h}, ${s}, ${l})`;
  }
}

function gameRunner() {
  let correctColor = randomColorGenerator();
  let randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 6);
  document.querySelectorAll(".gameColorOption").forEach((btn) => {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = randomColorGenerator();
  });
  document.querySelectorAll(".gameColorOption")[
    randomNumber
  ].style.backgroundColor = correctColor;

  document.querySelector(".gameQtsColor").innerHTML = correctColor;
  document.querySelectorAll(".gameColorOption").forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (e.target.style.backgroundColor === correctColor) {
        document.querySelector(".gameMessage").innerHTML = "Correct!";
        document.querySelectorAll(".gameColorOption").forEach((btn) => {
          btn.style.backgroundColor = correctColor;
        });
      } else {
        document.querySelector(".gameMessage").innerHTML = "Wrong!";
        e.target.style.transform = "scale(1.2)";
        e.target.style.border = "4px solid red";
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gochi+Hand&display=swap");
body {
  background-color: #456064;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #2e4144;
  font-family: "Gochi Hand", cursive;
  font-size: 28px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #456064;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.colorCodeSelection {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.colorCodeBtn:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
}

.colorCodeBtn:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
}

.colorCodeBtn {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-family: "Gochi Hand", cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.selectedColorCode {
  background-color: white;
  color: #456064;
}

.gameContainer {
  font-family: "Gochi Hand", cursive;
  color: white;
}

.gameQtsColor {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.gameColorsContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.gameOptionsRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gameColorOption {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 25px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.gameColorOption:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
  box-shadow: 4px 6px 24px hsla(188, 19%, 20%, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Colors and Numbers</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand ms-2 mt-2 me-5" href="/">
        <i class="bi bi-palette-fill"></i> &
        <i class="bi bi-dice-3-fill"></i>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Game</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/generator">
                Generator
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/converter">
                Converter
              </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--* Navbar End -->
  <!-- Game Body -->
  <div class="colorCodeSelection">
    <button class="colorCodeBtn selectedColorCode" game-mode="rgb">RGB</button>
    <button class="colorCodeBtn" game-mode="hex">HEX</button>
    <button class="colorCodeBtn" game-mode="hsl">HSL</button>
  </div>
  <div class="gameContainer container mt-5">
    <p class="h3 text-center mt-5">Which Color is this?</p>
    <p class="gameQtsColor text-center">rgb(20, 30, 40)</p>
    <p class="text-center h3 gameMessage">Select from below!</p>
    <div class="gameColorsContainer container-fluid">
      <div class="gameOptionsRow">
        <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
        <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
        <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="gameOptionsRow">
        <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
        <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
        <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: So, if you console.log `selectedGameMode` before `gameRunner` it displays the correct value? How does `gameRunner` handle the game mode selected?

Comment: @beto `gameRunner` has nothing to do with the selected game mode. The `selectedGameMode` is only for the `randomColorGenerator()` function

Comment: And where are you executing `randomColorGenerator()`? Shouldn't it be executed after you set the `selectedGameMode` and before the game runs?

Comment: can you add more context around that first snippet of code? How is that called? Is it in a function? Why are you adding click events to the same buttons that execute that code?

Comment: @beto The `randomColorGenerator()` is being called inside the `gameRunner()` when I have to decide of a color

Comment: @AndrewLohr okay Sure

Comment: I ran your code and it looks like the game mode does change. You explained well on how your code works, but can you be more specific on what is actually going wrong?

Comment: @AndrewLohr basically it is changing the game mode from what I see in the log but, when playing the game, the game does not change the colors as per the hsl values or hex values when I saw in the browser

Comment: @AndrewLohr that means that the `selectedGameMode` isn't changing in the `gameRunner` even though it changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues I see

1. Setting background colour via element.style.backgroundColor is going to convert the value you set to rgb/a, so regardless of whether you use hex or hsl you'll end up with rgb(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208559/browsers-automatically-evaluate-hex-or-hsl-colors-to-rgb-when-setting-via-elemen)).
   If you want to keep the method of style you use, you can use setAttribute/getAttribute to set the colour and to get it back to test.
2. The way you construct your hsl and hex colours looked incorrect(see code changes)
3. The  `correctColor` variable was not changing, this was because of the closure created by the event listeneters added to the `.gameColorOption` divs. I made this variable global to avoid that problem.
4. Your `randomNumber` code can generate a value of 6 which would be too large to select a `.gameColorOption` and would cause an error. Use `Math.round(Math.random() * 5)`

   ```js
   let selectedGameMode = "rgb";
   let correctColor;
   gameRunner();
   document.querySelectorAll(".colorCodeBtn").forEach((btn) => {
     btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
       if (btn.classList.contains("selectedColorCode")) return;
       btn.parentElement
         .querySelector(".selectedColorCode")
         .classList.remove("selectedColorCode");
       btn.classList.add("selectedColorCode");
       selectedGameMode = btn.getAttribute("game-mode");
       gameRunner();
     });
   });

   function randomColorGenerator() {
     let red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
     let green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
     let blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
     if (selectedGameMode == "rgb") {
       return `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
     } else if (selectedGameMode == "hex") {
       let hexRed = red.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
       let hexGreen = green.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
       let hexBlue = blue.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
       return `#${hexRed + hexGreen + hexBlue}`;
     } else if (selectedGameMode == "hsl") {
       let h = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
       let s = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + "%";
       let l = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + "%";
       return `hsl(${h}deg ${s} ${l})`;
     }
   }

   function gameRunner() {
     correctColor = randomColorGenerator();
     let randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
     document.querySelectorAll(".gameColorOption").forEach((btn) => {
       btn.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: ' + randomColorGenerator());
     });
     document.querySelectorAll(".gameColorOption")[
       randomNumber
     ].setAttribute('style', 'background-color: ' + correctColor);

     document.querySelector(".gameQtsColor").innerHTML = correctColor;
     document.querySelectorAll(".gameColorOption").forEach((btn) => {
       btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
         if (e.target.getAttribute('style').substr(18) === correctColor) {
           document.querySelector(".gameMessage").innerHTML = "Correct!";
           document.querySelectorAll(".gameColorOption").forEach((btn) => {
             btn.style.backgroundColor = correctColor;
           });
         } else {
           document.querySelector(".gameMessage").innerHTML = "Wrong!";
           e.target.style.transform = "scale(1.2)";
           e.target.style.border = "4px solid red";
         }
       });
     });
   }
   ```

   ```css
   @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gochi+Hand&display=swap");
   body {
     background-color: #456064;
   }

   .navbar {
     background-color: #2e4144;
     font-family: "Gochi Hand", cursive;
     font-size: 28px;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #456064;
     box-shadow: 0px 6px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
   }

   .navbar-brand {
     font-size: 28px;
   }

   .nav-link:hover {
     text-decoration: underline;
   }

   .colorCodeSelection {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
   }

   .colorCodeBtn:first-child {
     border-top-left-radius: 100px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
   }

   .colorCodeBtn:last-child {
     border-top-right-radius: 100px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
   }

   .colorCodeBtn {
     margin: 0;
     margin-top: 20px;
     outline: none;
     background-color: transparent;
     border: 1px solid white;
     font-family: "Gochi Hand", cursive;
     /*color: white;*/
     font-size: 24px;
   }

   .selectedColorCode {
     background-color: white;
     color: #456064;
   }

   .gameContainer {
     font-family: "Gochi Hand", cursive;
     /*color: white;*/
   }

   .gameQtsColor {
     font-size: 60px;
     line-height: 60px;
   }

   .gameColorsContainer {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
   }

   .gameOptionsRow {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
   }

   .gameColorOption {
     background-color: chartreuse;
     height: 150px;
     width: 150px;
     margin: 25px;
     border-radius: 16px;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
   }

   .gameColorOption:hover {
     transform: scale(1.15);
     box-shadow: 4px 6px 24px hsla(188, 19%, 20%, 0.3);
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">

   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
     <title>Colors and Numbers</title>
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   </head>

   <body>
     <!-- Navbar -->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <a class="navbar-brand ms-2 mt-2 me-5" href="/">
           <i class="bi bi-palette-fill"></i> &
           <i class="bi bi-dice-3-fill"></i>
         </a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
           <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Game</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/generator">
                   Generator
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/converter">
                   Converter
                 </a>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
     </nav>
     <!--* Navbar End -->
     <!-- Game Body -->
     <div class="colorCodeSelection">
       <button class="colorCodeBtn selectedColorCode" game-mode="rgb">RGB</button>
       <button class="colorCodeBtn" game-mode="hex">HEX</button>
       <button class="colorCodeBtn" game-mode="hsl">HSL</button>
     </div>
     <div class="gameContainer container mt-5">
       <p class="h3 text-center mt-5">Which Color is this?</p>
       <p class="gameQtsColor text-center">rgb(20, 30, 40)</p>
       <p class="text-center h3 gameMessage">Select from below!</p>
       <div class="gameColorsContainer container-fluid">
         <div class="gameOptionsRow">
           <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
           <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
           <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="gameOptionsRow">
           <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
           <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
           <div class="gameColorOption"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </body>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>

   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in your code:

```
let randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 6);
```

This can round to a `6`, meaning that when it does turn into a `6`, the line:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".gameColorOption")[randomNumber].setAttribute('style', 'background-color: ' + correctColor);
```

targets an `undefined` element. Remember that arrays and array-like structures start at index 0, so you only want numbers between 0 and 5 for your 6 color tiles.

This is what causes your game mode to get into a bad state. If you click around on your buttons a bunch, eventually you will see the error in the console:

```
js:220 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
    at gameRunner (js:220)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (js:184)
```

---

To ensure you only get a number between 0 and 5, you should change this to be:

```
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
```

Comment: Still doesn't solve why the colors in the game options aren't changed after changing the game mode. But still, I will make sure to fix this one. Thanks