# How to have the color input element output values in hex and not RGB

Tags: javascript, input, colors

I have a color input like this

```js
function setstyle(elm, val) {
  elm.style.color = val;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" name="fontcolor" id="fontcolor" value="#ffffff" onchange="setstyle('usermsg',this.value);">
```

when you choose a color this will automatically change the style in a separate text area. However, despite the input is in hex, it will always output it as RGB which I don't need. How can I fix that so it adds the equivalent hex value?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1a23t6w0/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208559/browsers-automatically-evaluate-hex-or-hsl-colors-to-rgb-when-setting-via-elemen

Comment: you mean its impossible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert rgb strings to hex in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070054/convert-rgb-strings-to-hex-in-javascript)

Comment: You can convert it to hex as in HM's link, and use that, but the browser will always style it as RGB.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59513865/215552) to the question @Andy posted, and the answers to the question I posted, show how to convert from RGB to hex format, if it's important. That said, the computed value will be in whatever format the browser wants it to be.

Comment: This is really weird. On dev tools if I do this fontcolor.value it outputs the value in hex on the console. So why will it display it otherwise for everything else?

Comment: ...Did you *read* the answers to the question posted in the very first comment?

Comment: yes, but still dont get it.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get hex color values out of a color input. Since you're already using javascript, also use it to convert the color to the format you desire.